# Asterisk CLI Verbose[?number?]

Tags: asterisk

In my CLI, I have entries like

```
VERBOSE[16933] logger.c: 
WARNING[8556] chan_sip.c:
VERBOSE[8556] logger.c:  
VERBOSE[16932] logger.c:
```

What is the significance of the number with the "[]" brackets?

Answer (score 2):

That is the PID of the process that logged the message.